# How to make a multi-line textbox's tab-stop working in win32api application

Tags: c, winapi, tabs

I have a win32api application written in c here. All controls in main window are created manually like this:

```
hEditSource = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", NULL,
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY,
                someLeft, someTop, someWidth, someHeight,
                hWndMain, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

At first I didn't apply IsDialogMessage test in main message loop so all controls' tab stop won't work. Now I have it done, every control are OK except the multi-line textbox above. Indeed nothing happens when press tab in it. No focus moving, no tab charactor inserting(it will discard read-only style afterwards).

Other textboxes are all single-line ones, looks like this:

```
editSearch = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", NULL,
               WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,
               someLeft, someTop, someWidth, someHeight,
               hWndMain, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

It seems sth related to multiple line style is the cause. But in C# winform, it is very easy to create a multi-line edit with working tab-stop (it is the default behavior of a textbox, whether it is multi-line). I have tried to use spy++, to find if there is any clue in window style. However, 2 textboxes' window style are indentical if the only difference is the "Accept Tab" property.

Rightnow I cannot find another way to locate the root cause. Does anyone have a clue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which behaviour do you want? Accept TAB key, or move to next control? And is there any chance we can see an SSCCE so that we can be sure that there are no other mistakes.

Comment: Move to the next control is what I want. And what is SSCCE? Full source code?

Comment: Yes. You can do a websearch to learn about SSCCE.

Comment: Greatly thanks for tearch about SSCCE. I need to do some refactoring for the code. I'll post it when completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour of the `IsDialogMessage` is influenced by how the controls respond to `WM_GETDLGCODE`. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-edit-controls), for a multi-line edit control the following is returned by the default window procedure:

```
 DLGC_WANTCHARS | DLGC_HASSETSEL | DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS
```

The inclusion of `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS` stops `IsDialogMessage` from responding to <kbd>TAB</kbd> and moving the focus to the next control. So, you will need to subclass your multi-line edit control and remove that flag. The sub-classed window procedure might look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MultiLineEditWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, 
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT res = CallWindowProc(wpOld, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
        res &= ~DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. It is right the one I'm looking for. However, since there is only 1 textbox need to be take care of, to subclass it seems a little complex. So I decided to intercept its tab key message in main message loop and manually move the focus. :)